# MySQL - Getting a position from a "leaderboard"

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by

I'm trying to construct a query where I would get a leaderboard-like result, then get the position on the leaderboard of a specific player, by their ID, and only if the player `isHere = 'true'` (stored in another table).

Table `here`:

```
 userID  |  isHere |
--------------------
   2    |   true
--------------------
   1    |   true
--------------------
   3    |   false
--------------------
   4    |   true
```

Table `userdata`:

```
   id   |         data            |
------------------------------------
   2    |   {... "points": 5 ...}
------------------------------------
   1    |   {... "points": 10 ...}
------------------------------------
   3    |   {... "points": 2 ...}
------------------------------------
   4    |   {... "points": 28 ...}
```

Query:

```
SET
  @row_number = 0;
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    (@row_number := @row_number +1) AS num,
    userdata.id,
    userdata.data
  FROM
    userdata
  INNER JOIN
    here ON userdata.id = here.userID
  WHERE
    here.isHere = 'true'
  ORDER BY
    JSON_EXTRACT(userdata.data,
    '$.points') DESC
) AS t
WHERE
  t.id = 1
```

This returns that `num` is 1... because for some reason it's sorting by userID/id. I double checked by setting `WHERE t.id =` as 2, and instead of returning 3, it returns 2... Does anyone know what's wrong with my query?

**Note:** I did try having the column `data` be just a `BIGINT` with the point value, but the same issue happened. So that eliminates `JSON_EXTRACT()` having any issues (I think?)

**Note 2:** Running the inner query on its own still orders by the ID with the `num` column, but displays in PHPMyAdmin in the correct order (Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/73177e79f4fedd4ec7e09ea0e70a9d2b)

Comment: Did you run the inner query by itself with also selecting the JSON extract and seeing what is going on?

Comment: @juergend It's a little confusing to me, here's what happened: https://gyazo.com/73177e79f4fedd4ec7e09ea0e70a9d2b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the query that works:

```
SET
  @row_number = 0;
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    (@row_number := @row_number +1) AS num,
    userdata.id,
    userdata.data
  FROM
    userdata
  INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
      userdata.id,
      userdata.data
    FROM
      userdata
    INNER JOIN
      here ON userdata.id = here.userID
    WHERE
      here.isHere = 'true'
    ORDER BY
      JSON_EXTRACT(userdata.data,
      '$.points') DESC
  ) AS t ON userdata.id = t.id
) AS t2
WHERE
  id = ?
```

The only reason all of this is needed, is due to the order in which MySQL executes parts of queries. Just like parenthesis are used in math in order of operations, I used a `SELECT` statement here.